# Somar o desmembramento de número

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde pessoal,

Tenho uma questão que não estou conseguindo resolver. Sou iniciante em programação e começando com Javascript.

Tenho um número inteiro, preciso pegar todos os números menores e iguais a ele e fazer a soma. Ex: número = 5. A soma da questão seria essa: 5+4+3+2+1.

Escrevi da seguinte maneira:

```
function somaNumero(numero) {
    var numero = i;
    var numero = (i * (i - 1))/2;
}
console.log(somaNumero);
```

Comment: Já pensou em um loop?

Comment: Marcelinha, o somatório de Gauss para se determinar a soma de todos os naturais até determinado número é dada por `function somaNumero(n) {
    return (n * (n + 1)) /2;
}

console.log(somaNumero(5));`

Comment: Leia: [Que erro eu cometi fazendo minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-eu-cometi-fazendo-minha-pergunta)

Comment: definiu duas vezes a variavel numero. Não definiu a variavel i. Não passou o valor na chamada da função  Faça assim, essa linha é desprezível var numero = i; portanto elimine-a. Mude os i por numero e troque o sinal - por sinal + Chame a função passando o valor console.log(somaNumero(5)); Essa solução está na abordagem matemática da minha resposta

Answer (score 2):

Um loop do numero passado para a função

```js
function somaNumero(numero) {
  var total = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= numero; i++){
      total += i;
    }
    return total;
}

//chama a função passando o numero
console.log(somaNumero(5));
```

> O problema com a implementação acima é que, conforme o número aumenta, aumenta também o número de iterações.

**Usar uma abordagem matemática** para encontrar a soma de N números pode remover completamente o uso do loop for. Vamos tentar resolver o problema acima com uma abordagem matemática.

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + …… .. + n
```

Vamos supor que a soma das séries acima seja total .

```
total = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
```

Agora vamos inverter a série e adicionar os números de trás para frente, o que também dará o mesmo total.

```
total = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + (n-4)
```

Vamos somar os dois totais

```
total + total = (n + 1) + ((n-1) + 2) + ((n-2) + 3) + ((n-3) + 4) + ((n-4) + 5)



2total = (n+1) + (n+1)+ (n+1)+ (n+1)+ (n+1)

2total = n(n+1)

total = (n(n+1))/2
```

ou seja (numero * (numero + 1)) / 2

**Resultado**

```js
function somaNumero(numero) {
  return (numero * (numero + 1)) / 2 
}

console.log(somaNumero(5));
```

Para aqueles que sabem o que é uma Progressão Aritmética – PA , basta observar que a fórmula da soma dos n primeiros termos da PA (a1,a2,a3,…,an) é dada por

Sn=a1+a2+…+an=((a1+an)⋅n)/2

Como (1,2,3,4,…,n) é uma PA, de razão 1, segue que a soma dos n
primeiros termos é dada por:

```
   (1+n)⋅n
  _________
      2
```

total = ((n+1)⋅n)/2